# Delta training rule for perceptron training

Tags: java, machine-learning, perceptron

I'm trying to train a perceptron for the AND boolean function using the delta training rule. But even after convergence, it's wrongly classifying the inputs (1 input actually). Could you please tell me where am I wrong : http://ideone.com/CDgTQE

This is the training function used:

```
public void trianWithDelta(Example[] examples){ 
    for(int i=0;i<1000;++i){

        dw1 = 0;
        dw2 = 0;

        for(Example ex:examples){
            double o = computeOutput(ex);
            double t = ex.o;

            dw1 = dw1 + n*(t-o)*ex.x1;
            dw2 = dw2 + n*(t-o)*ex.x2;
        } 

        w1 += dw1;
        w2 += dw2; 
    }        
}
```

The training examples (boolean AND):

```
Example[] examples = new Example[]{
        new Example(-1, -1, -1),
        new Example(-1 , 1, -1),
        new Example( 1, -1, -1),
        new Example( 1,  1, 1)
    };
```

Results :
    w1 : 0.49999999999999994 w2 : 0.5000000000000002

Tests using the training examples after training :

-1

1 (incorrect)

-1

1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually **correct**, the problem lies in your understanding of what can be learned using an unbiased perceptron and what can't.

If you do not have a bias, then learning AND is nearly impossible because:

- there is exactly **one** angle separating your data, which is realized for line `y=-x`, in your code it would mean that `w1=w2`, and even slightest difference between their values will break the classifier (such as `1e-20`)
- you classifier actualy answers three values (as you use sign function): -1, 0, 1 while it is impossible to separate AND without bias in such setting, as you need to answer -1 when activation is 0.

Try to draw the correct separator on piece of paper, you will notice, that without bias your line has to cross (0,0), thus, it has to be y=-x, and consequently for (-1,1) and (1,-1) the activation is 0.

[image]

Both problems can be solved by just adding bias node (and this is what you should do).

[image]

You can also change "a bit" definition of AND - for example by encoding "False" as -2

```
Example[] examples = new Example[]{
        new Example(-2, -2, -2),
        new Example(-2 , 1, -2),
        new Example( 1, -2, -2),
        new Example( 1,  1, 1)
    };
```

[image]

And runing your code behaves as expected

```
Trained weights : 0.6363636363636364 0.6363636363636364
-1
-1
-1
1
```